# Hiding individual views inside a group in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-view, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to hide individual views inside a group of a constraint layout.
I tried and failed & ultimately moved that view outside the group.
I did not find any document mentioning this behaviour.

Any one who can confirm?

Comment: What is your current code looks like?

Comment: You give up control over the visibility of individual views in a group. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510720/6287910).

Comment: Yes, It's absolutely possible.

Answer (score 0):

whats you used for hide a view means INVSIBLE that take space of component and visiblity GONE not take any space of component .. so other component will effect.

can you show me your current code that i can understand properly.

thanks