# Cannot change visibilty of a View that is being referenced inside a constraintlayout Group

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Cannot change visibilty of an individual  View that is being referenced inside a 
 constraintlayout Group

*Using*     **implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'**

Tried with **implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'** (Stable version)
but not working.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bgView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/full"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bulletinsRV"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->handler.onClickPieChart(v)}"
            app:centerText="@{`Total Due:`+  vm.home.payment.totalAmount +` AED`}"
            app:centerTextSize="@{vm.home.payment.paymentStatus.equals(`FullyPaid`)?0F:12F}"
            app:description="@{vm.home.payment.paymentStatus.equals(`FullyPaid`)?``:`My payment`}"
            app:dueCleared="@{vm.home.payment.paymentStatus.equals(`FullyPaid`)}"
            app:goneWhen="@{vm.home.payment == null}"
            app:isRotationEnabled="@{false}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:pieEntries="@{vm.pieEntries}"
            app:touchEnabled="@{false}" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="bgView,chart"
            app:visibleIf="@{vm.isUnitInitialized}" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try to modify the code in build.gradle by using this implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

Comment: used this but its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you see the documentation for Group on the [developer’s website](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Group), it seems that grouping is responsible for Visibility and Elevation.

> This class controls the visibility of a set of referenced widgets. [...] The visibility of the group will be applied to the referenced widgets. It's a convenient way to easily hide/show a set of widgets without having to maintain this set programmatically.

The idea seems to be that if not all views share the same visibility and elevation then they quite possibly shouldn’t belong to the same group.

The default Constraint Helper class responsible for setting the views’ visibility in a group, seems to be applying the same value to all children of a group, so you wouldn’t be able to override it individually for some views.

This is the relevant code in the default Helper:

```
 public void updatePreLayout(ConstraintLayout container) {
    int visibility = getVisibility();
    float elevation = 0;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        elevation = getElevation();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
        int id = mIds[i];
        View view = container.getViewById(id);
        if (view != null) {
            view.setVisibility(visibility);
            if (elevation > 0 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                view.setElevation(elevation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/sherpa/+/studio-3.2.1/constraintlayout/src/main/java/android/support/constraint/Group.java))

In order to achieve what you want, you would either need to create multiple groups, one that includes the individual view that you want to change amongst the others, and one with all the views together. If you want to change the visibility of one view you change the visibility of your smaller group, otherwise, you change the visibility of the group that contains them all.

In your case where you only have two views, it seems like a ridiculous idea though. So I think alternatively you would have to create your custom  Constraint Helper.

**EDIT:** [Here's a discussion on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510720/10300673)